# Colocar Json local em Json externo $http Angular / Ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, http, ionic

Eu quero puxar esses dados Json do Service por um Json Externo via $http. Achei vários exemplos mais eles não estão retornando resultado pra mim.

```
.service('ProdutosService', function($q) {
return {
produtos: [

  {
     "nomeProd": "nomeproduto",
     "codCat": "nomecategoria",
     "id": "01"
  },
  {
     "nomeProd": "nomeproduto2",
     "codCat": "nomecategoria2",
     "id": "02"
  },

],

getProdutos: function() {
  return this.produtos
},

getProduto: function(produtoId) {
  var dfd = $q.defer()
  this.produtos.forEach(function(produto) {
    if (produto.id === produtoId) dfd.resolve(produto)
  })

    return dfd.promise
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Você pode explicar qual o problema que está tentando resolver? Clique em [edit] e adicione mais detalhes à sua publicação.

Comment: eu tenho esse json produtos, mais ele esta dentro do service. Eu quero puxar esse json de um arquivo externo, usando $http.

Comment: Você quer pegar esses dados de produtos de um servidor?

Comment: eu tenho um arquivo json externo e quero puxar esse json pra dentro do service via $http. O caminho do arquivo é js/produtos.json.

Comment: Se você quer puxar via $http você precisa ter um servidor

Comment: dentro do $http.get não pode colocar um arquivo local. Exemplo: $http.get("js/produtos.json")

Comment: Não posso te afirmar com certeza, mas possivelmente não. Se tiver como será uma grande gambiarra, deve ter outras formas de pegar esse arquivo sem ser por http

Comment: e como ficaria este json em um servidor. Eu tenho este arquivo hospedado em um servidor. Como faria pra puxar ele pra dentro do Service?

Comment: Por $http. Exemplo: `$http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4");`

Comment: sim..mais como ficaria a estrutura do service com essa $http. Ja fiz várias tentativas mais nenhuma deu certo.

Comment: Existem varias maneiras de se montar a estrutura do service, eu faço dessa forma: http://pastebin.com/3DMuY1FR

Comment: Note que no $http.get estou usando o ip local, onde tenho um servidor me enviando dados no formato Json

Answer (score 1):

Você pode puxar os arquivos que estão no projeto ou em um servidor externo usando o $http.get, já tentou desta forma? Só vou alterar sua getProdutos, não consigo testar agora o código completo, veja se te ajuda.

```
getProdutos: function () {
    $http.get('js/produtos.json').then(function (retorno) {
         this.produtos = retorno.data;
         return this.produtos;
    })
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz da maneira q vc me descreveu, mais retorno erro no console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

@André Vicente

Comment: da um console.log(retorno) para ver o que está retornando, pode ser que não precise do data

Comment: nada meu...continua dando o mesmo erro...nem o resultado do console apareceu. Inclusive deletei o data no retorno.data e mesmo assim deu o mesmo erro @AndréVicente

Comment: Parece ter um "(" errado no código. Pode até ser em outra parte do seu código. Vê direito no erro se mostra a linha onde está o erro. Senão da uma revisada em tudo para ver se não tem coisa sobrando ou faltando ai. Tira todo o http.get e testa, se continuar o erro tira todo o service para ver se ainda está com o erro, vai testando até achar.

Comment: o erro ta na linha "getProdutos: function(){ @AndréVicente

Comment: Criei esse service em um projeto meu e não tive esse erro. Você consegue jogar no codepen ou editar seu código para vermos como está agora?